# Loop through a collection without a 'value' property in Tapestry

Tags: tapestry

The [Tapestry loop documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tapestry-core/ref/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Loop.html) shows the following example

```html
<t:loop source="pageNames" value="pageName">
    <td class="${tabClass}">
        <t:pagelink page="pageName">${pageName}</t:pagelink>
    </td>
</t:loop>
```

where the pageName variable is picked up from the Component:

```java
@Property
private String _pageName;
```

I have no use for such a property. Removing the declaration from the Component makes Tapestry sad and throw an Exception similar to

> Could not convert 'pageName' into a component parameter binding. Class ... does not contain a property named 'pageName' (within property expression 'pageName'). Available properties: ...

How can I use a loop tag without declaring a property for the loop value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to specify `t:value`, just leave it out. In some cases, you just want to use `t:index`, that's totally fine.

*Edit based on comment:*

Yes, there is no way around declaring a property in the component class. It can look slightly inelegant when you don't do anything with the current iteration value inside the component class, that's true. I tend to use getters and setters instead of the `@Property` annotation in such cases to avoid the "unused" compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The point is that if I want to access some sort of information from the iteration, like the value and the index, I need to declare a property, right?

Comment: @Robert: Now I see what you were after, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix the temporary variable in the template with the var prefix. So in your case, you would just say `value="var:pagename"`. This works fine if pagename is a primitive such as a string or integer and you can access its value anywhere in the loop using the following syntax `${var:pagename}`. It fails however when you try to access its properties, such as `pagename.name`.

Have a look [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-UsingBindingExpressions) for a list of available binding expressions to see other places (such as message catalogs) where you can pull values from.

Or you can always use `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` in your page class over the property to supress the compiler warning.

Cheers.